# Settings in Info.plist are ignored in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

I am facing following problem. In the `Info.plist` file of my iOS project I have set several values like `status bar style` to `Opaque black style`. I also have set `Icon already includes gloss effects` to `YES`.

But both seem to be ignored. The icon has still gloss and the status bar is standard grey.

When I start the application the status bar is black but when it finishes launching it gets grey.

In my storyboard I have set the status bar to black:

[image]

I also set it to black via code. Still grey. I use the three20 lib in my project

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a third-party library such as Three20, or just a standard UIViewController subclass?

Comment: This is the issue. Try creating your own subclass of TTStyleSheet http://mattvague.com/three20-stylesheets-tutorial and setting your status bar style there.

Comment: In there20, if you're using TTBaseViewController or a subclass, you need to set statusBarStyle on your view controller. See: https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UICommon/Sources/TTBaseViewController.m

Answer (score 3):

Right click inside the info.plist and select "Show Raw Keys/Values"

Make sure that the key is `UIStatusBarStyle` and the value is a string, `UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque`

If you are just typing status bar style, it won't work.

Also, make sure that the Info.plist you are editing is the same one being loaded.  do a search for plist in your build settings to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the statusBar style in you code. Try writing something like this in your appDelegate's appDidFinishLaunching:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

Comment: The problem might be that one of your .xib files tell the statusBar to be gray. Check the attribute inspector in your MainWindow.xib (or what you might have called it).

Answer (score 0):

Check the previous view; maybe you overwrote the status bar on some method.

Comment: what do you mean with tabbar? I have no tabbar in my project

Comment: ah yes I have selected black on both, however no effect

Comment: try 
- [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
      setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent animated:NO]; 
or  
- [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
      setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:NO];

Comment: I put this in the application didFinishLaunchingWihtOptions method but still no effect, while launching its black when finished launching it fades gray

Comment: hmmmm. try this
 Add following settings in the Info.plist file:
- UIStatusBarStyle UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque
UIApplication Class
Set following inside the app delegate:
- [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
- [[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
      setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:NO];  
- [[UIApplication sharedApplication]

Comment: sorry for my english))) try add UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque on  Info.plist file and them 
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque animated:NO];
on appDelegate